# Coldfusion - Structure and dynamic variables names

Tags: coldfusion, structure, coldfusion-11, dynamic-variables

I have problem for getting and working on a structure containing dynamic variable names. I have a structure *cfStruct* which contains another structure *EMAILS*. In the last structure the maximum of items is 4

Here my structure for EMAILS

```
EMAILS":{"1":"mail1@test.com","2":"mail2@test.net","3":"mail3@test.fr"}
```

I try to create one variable for each item of this structure if it exists by doing that. Nevertheless it doesn't work:

```
    <cfif IsDefined("cfStruct.EMAILS")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
            <cfif StructKeyExists( cfStruct.EMAILS, '#i#' ) >
                <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", "#cfStruct.EMAILS.i#" >
            <cfelse>
                <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", '') >
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>       
    <cfelse>
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Regards,

Comment: How about this?  <cfset variables["EMAIL_#i#"] = fStruct.EMAILS.i>

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cleanest was to write this is:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfif StructKeyExists( cfStruct.EMAILS, i ) >
        <cfset variables["EMAIL_#i#"] = cfStruct.EMAILS[i] >
    <cfelse>
        <cfset variables["EMAIL_#i#"] = '' >
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

For the following reasons:

- No unnecessary string expressions. Every time you do `'#i#'` you're telling CF to parse the string, evaluate the expressions within it, and return a new string in place of this one..
- Explicit is better than implicit, using `variables["EMAIL_#i#"]` tells you exactly where you've put the variable you're creating so when you come to re-read months later it's crystal clear what's going on.

#### Bonus

If you change your loop to `<cfloop from="1" to="#structCount(cfStruct.EMAILS)#" index="i">` then your code won't create more variables than needed (if this effect is desired) and could scale up to any number struct values.

Comment: Good points.  "return a new string in place of this one" Agreed, using quotes is unnecessary, but I believe CF will still return the same string. Unless you change the value by say ... adding characters or using use concatenation.

Comment: It will indeed return the same value, but it will generate additional data during the interpolation routines which will need to be garbage collected, and hold the memory until then. It always pays to remember that strings are immutable in Java so anytime you change of modify strings you are potentially using more resource than necessary and trusting the compiler to optimize your string manipulation for you.

Comment: True, but java has String pooling. Since the string wasn't changed, I would think it would be pulled from the pool. Have you read anything that says CF behaves differently? I'm curious how CF handles it but couldn't find anything definitive on the topic :)

Comment: The string doesn't change, but the first string created is '#i#' as a literal, there are many approaches cf could take and they've none too transparent about how they do it. But what I do know is that for a long time, lucee and its precursor railo performed string interpolation faster than cf, And building your strings with concatenation techniques where possible ran faster on cf. This difference however was only noticeable on larger datasets. The right technique would allow the compiler to produce more optimised bytecode and the difference was/is measurable.

Comment: Yeah, but string literals are usually interned. So it seemed more likely CF *wouldn't* create a new string in this case. Though, I could definitely see concatenation being different, as it could potentially create many different strings, depending on how it's implemented. Either way, since the internal behavior isn't known, IMO it's not entirely accurate to say "*will* return a new string" since we don't know for certain how CF behaves under the hood ;-) That said, I agree that type of unnecessary quoting should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem it was a syntax problem:

```
    <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
        <cfif StructKeyExists( cfStruct.EMAILS, '#i#' ) >
            <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", "#cfStruct.EMAILS[i]#") >
        <cfelse>
            <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", '') >
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you should use cfStruct.EMAILS["#i#"] instead of "#cfStruct.EMAILS[i]#". That is,

```
<cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <cfif StructKeyExists( cfStruct.EMAILS, "#i#" ) >
        <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", cfStruct.EMAILS["#i#"]) >
    <cfelse>
        <cfset setVariable( "EMAIL_#i#", '') >
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```